# Pass value from table in modal to input outside modal in the same row

Tags: jquery, html-table, modal-dialog

I have a button inside a table row that when clicked, query stuff via ajax and returns in a table inside a modal.

Then, in the modal, I have another button to send one value from a `<td>` back to the parent form, inside a specific input.

This is my code:

```
$('table').on("click", ".search", function(){
            var trparent = $(this).closest('tr');

            // ajax query here

            });

            $('table').on("click", "#add", function() {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var number = tr.find('td:eq(0)').text();
                    $('#modal').modal('hide');
                    trparent.find("input[name$='[codigo]']").val(number);
            });
        });
```

Right now, it works but only for one search.
If I do a second search, the value append to the current `<tr>` and the previous `<tr>` aswell.
The problem is probably with this line `var trparent = $(this).closest('tr');`, is there a way to reset this variable everytime I click `.search`? Maybe this is super easy to do, but I am stuck in this for a while now.

Here is a gif to make understanding easier:

[image]

Comment: Personally I would  add a selected class instead. Easy to find it again and easy to remove

Comment: Add a selected class on the tr? Could you give me an example? I dont understand much of jquery/js

Comment: In search button `$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected'); $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected')` ... then in add `$('tr.selected').find("input[name$=....`

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl, it worked. Easier indeed.